# Character Concatenation Resulting in Numerical Output

Tags: java, character, concatenation

In a programming language called Java, I have the following line of code:

```
char u = 'U';
System.out.print(u + 'X');
```

This statement results in an output like this:

```
173
```

Instead of

```
UX
```

Am I missing something? Why isn't it outputing 'UX'? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are performing an addition of chars. In Java, when you add chars, they are first converted to integers. In your case, the ASCII code of U is 85 and the code for X is 88.

And you print the sum, which is 173.

If you want to concatenate the chars, you can do, for example:

```
System.out.print("" + u + 'X');
```

Now the `+` is not a char addition any more, it becomes a String concatenation (because the first parameter `""` is a String).

You could also create the String from its characters:

```
char[] characters = {u, 'X'};
System.out.print(new String(characters));
```

Answer (score 3):

In this language known as Java, the result of adding two chars, shorts, or bytes [is an int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

Thus, the integer value of `U` (85) is added to the integer value of `X` (88) and you get an integer value of `173` (85+88).

**To Fix:**

You'll probably want to make `u` a string.  A string plus a *char* will be a string, as will a string plus a string.

```
String u = "U"; // u is a string
System.out.print(u + 'X'); // string plus a char is a string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String u = "U";
System.out.print(u + "X");
```

instead of `char` type use `String` class or `StringBuilder` class

Comment: Note `"X"` can also be `'X'` if you want, since a string plus a char will also use string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert one of the characters to a string:

```
char u = 'U';
System.out.print(Character.toString(u) + 'X');
```

This way could be useful when your variable is of type `char` for a good reason and you can't easily redeclare it as a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

That "language called Java" bit amused me.

A quick search for "java concatenate" (which I recommend you do now and every time you have a question) revealed that most good Java programmers hate using `+` for concatenation. Even if it isn't used numerically when you want string concatenation, like in your code, it is also slow.

It seems that a much better way is to create a StringBuffer object and then call its `append` method for each string you want to be concatenated to it. See here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/string_concatenation.html

Comment: (i) `+`, when used for String concatenation in a single statement will be automatically converted to StringBuilder#append at compile time. It is only when you concatenate several times (typically in a loop) that your comment applies. (ii) the article your link to is obsolete - you should almost never use StringBuffer and you should use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Since that article was written in 2001, I'd question whether the lab tests quoted in the article (comparing the efficiency of the two approaches) are still valid.  A clever compiler *could* ensure that something like `System.out.println(aStudent + " received a grade of " + aGrade);` is no less efficient than the `StringBuilder` approach.  I'd agree that using `StringBuilder` is better than using `+=` in a loop, but it seems heavy for a simple expression like the above.

Comment: Oops. Normally searching for the answer is a good idea, but I guess it doesn't compensate for not knowing the language.

Comment: Plus, the recommended sample code in this "best practices" article would output "James Bondreceived a grade ofA".  There are some needed spaces missing.  Is it a good idea to trust the "best practice" recommendation of an author who can't even get that right????????????  I guess he didn't think "testing one's code before publishing it in an article" was a Best Practice.  :)